# Multiple-level nested imports in Python

Tags: python, import, structure

I am currently working in the following project, and running into some difficulty with imports. I previously came from a Ruby background before Python, so I suspect I'm just missing something.

```
-src
--project
---actions
----some .py files
---config
----some .py files
---db
----some .py files
-tests
--some .py files
-run.py
```

Some of the actions I'd like to do are:

- import src/project/config/file.py from `run.py`
- import between second level folder in `project` (ie. file in `actions` imports something from `config`)
- import any file into a test

Would anyone have any advice on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

So it's quite easy to reference something going deeper into the directory . For example, from run.py, you would be able to use something such as:

```
    from src.project.config.file import foo
```

It's easy to access something in the same directory as well, say you're in src/file1.py  trying to access src/file2.py, this would just be:

```
    from file2 import foo
```

This works too. However if you were trying to import upward say from file.py to run.py and tried running something like this:

```
    from ... import run.foo
```

You would get the following error:

```
    ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

The problem is that Python is assuming that your top-level package is wherever the file being run is located. That's why you can import everything on the same level and deeper but can't get at anything above.

An easy hack to get past this is to just append the path to your file to your `sys.path` so:

```
    import sys
    sys.append('path/to/run')
    from run import foo
```

So that's the answer to you question.

Based on the way your project is setup though it seems like you want to make a module and that's a bit more hands on, I suggest reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) it's pretty good.

Comment: This worked, once I upgraded to Python 3.3+ . I found I was not able to get it to work in Python 2.7 unless `src` was a package as well, which felt like a mistake (since you should never import all of src).